# Infinite mining, technically how is that coded

Tags: mining, dapp-development

For a token that can be mined forever, what are technical ways to do that?

One idea for infinite mining where at 21 billion, the token supply is reset to 21 million (everyone’s ownership is reset to 0.001%, so from 1000 TOKEN to 1 TOKEN.

Is there any blockchains or dApps or coins or tokens that do infinite mining, and how do they do it?

Comment: did you mean infinite minting?

Answer (score 1):

The question has some misunderstanding about how mining works. Mining rewards are a protocol choice and decided upon coin launch. In code, the node respects this decision by rejecting invalid blocks that do not stick to the mining reward plan. Of course, the community can bypass this limit by launching competitive code for a node and forking to it.

Eg, Dogecoin was launched with a fixed supply, later on(current) community moved to infinite supply(mining forever).